# Clang and '-O2' - disable specific optimization

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, compiler-optimization

For performance reasons I have to use -O2 optimization level on my code. The problem is that compiler promotes short strings (8 bytes or less) to registers, like:

```
__text:00000000001348DA                 mov     rcx, 3D3D3D3D3D3D3D3Dh
__text:00000000001348E4                 mov     [rax+10h], rcx
__text:00000000001348E8                 mov     [rax+8], rcx
__text:00000000001348EC                 mov     rcx, 3D3D3D3D3D3D3D0Ah
```

Which is equal to load string "\n========================".

I need to keep strings as data constants, prevent promoting them to registers. And I have to keep -O2 optimization for performance. clang is based on LLVM 10.

I'm asking or help, as I cannot find a flag that turning off such optimization pass.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring those specific strings as volatile should prevent this from happening, but, the real question is why is it bad for you?

Comment: My problem that I have a lot of such strings, so compiler flag is preferable.

Why? I have an optimization pass after the O2 that works with strings in _const section, and some strings are missed due to optimization.

Comment: You adjust/optimize the binary result?

Comment: My pass working on intermediate representation. Still it is too late at this stage, strings are already promoted to registers. I have tried to manually run reg2mem pass, but no effect.